# I have an error with browserHistory and react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Someone can help me please, I want to use react router but, but I have an error that I can not fix .

My error is : 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

My code Below

Thanks ^^

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Router, Route, Link,browserHistory,IndexRoute} from 'react-router'
import PostList from './containers/post_list'

class Routes extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path="/" component={PostList}/>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Routes
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class PostList extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Liste des posts</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostList;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import Routes from './routes.js';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Routes/>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Router v4 does not contain `browserHistory`.

Either downgrade to v3 or rewrite things to use v4.

See e.g. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732

Comment: Thanks AKX  :)  that's it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AKX ^^

The right way below

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import PostList from './containers/post_list';


class Routes extends Component {
    render () {
        return (

            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path="/new" component={PostList}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default Routes
```